# How to prevent text from wrapping a floated image when it grows?

Tags: html, css, css-float

How can I align text with an image if even if the text is longer than the image?

[image]

The words "*comfort and hope*" are not aligning with the rest of the text right of the image.

```
<style>
    .left { float: left; margin: 0em .5em .5em 0; padding-top:5px; padding-left:5px; }
    .right { float: right; margin: 0 0 .5em .5em; }
    .text {margin-right: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top:5px;}
    table, th, td {padding: 0px; border: 4px solid white; background-color:#e5e5e5; height:150px; width: 620px}
</style>

<td><a href="/grief-loss/"><img src="/uploads/2013/07/grief-loss.png" width="99" height="123" class="left"><div class="text"><b>Grief, Loss & End of Life Issues</b></a><br> The loss of a loved one can be life changing.  Grief is a difficult and continual journey in which additional support can provide comfort and hope.</div></td>
</tr>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property with a value different than `visible` to the `.text` div element in order to prevent the content from wrapping the floated image.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/jemuv/1/edit)**

```css
.text {
    overflow-x: auto; /* or hidden; */
    /* overflow property would create a new block formatting context         */
    /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/block_formatting_context */
}
```

---

Or `float` the `.text` element to left as well as the image *(As [@MrAlien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462545/aligning-text-to-an-image-that-goes-beyond-the-size-of-the-image/22462582?noredirect=1#comment34166692_22462582) suggested)*, make sure you assign some `width` to the floating elements. (**[Example here](http://jsbin.com/jemuv/2/edit)**)

---

Alternatively, you could set a left `margin` *(>= `width` of the floated image)* to the `.text` element:

```css
.text {
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top:5px;
  margin-left: 110px; /* <-- Added margin */
}
```

**[Updated example](http://jsbin.com/jemuv/3/edit)**.

Comment: Or `.text` should be floated to the `left` as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block instead of floating

```
.img, .copy { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 0 0.5em; max-width: 100px }

<div class="img">My Image</div>
<div class="copy">This is my long area of copy that is taller than the height of the image.</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tCQ26/