# Align text to the right of an image using CSS?

Tags: css, html

I'm attempting to align text to the right of an image;

css

```
.p1 {
position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 70%;; 
}
```

html

```
<img src=../images/diagram1.png alt="Diagram"/>
<span class="p1">This is a testtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt </span>
```

The code works for a short amount of text, but for a large amount of text it gets squished and forms a really long paragraph. Here is what I mean;

```
[image] [tes
         ttt
         ttt
         tt]
```

I want the text to appear as a normal paragraph block.

```
[image] [testttt
         ttttttt]
```

Comment: If you want the image and text to be totally separate from one another rather than just floating the text around the image, then you can put both the image and the text in container divs and set the container divs to `display: inline;`, with `float: left;` and  `float: right` set respectively.

Comment: Hi sorry, can you give an example in jsfiddle please?

Comment: when you test long text, don't just do one large word :), use fake text . search for _lorem ipsum_  generator

Comment: @Eggy This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462545/how-to-prevent-text-from-wrapping-a-floated-image-when-it-grows/22462582#22462582

Comment: @Eggy I am may be wrong about you requirement but simple float may sort this out http://jsfiddle.net/LcFD9/1/

Comment: remove the `width:100px`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Gaby yours worked <3

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Eggy Please find [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cooolkiran/nSm37/)

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container img{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to remove the absolute positioning and give the img and text inline-block displays. You may also want to remove your width of the paragraph or increase it: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeV4W/2/)

CSS

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
}
.p1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 70%;
}
```